# How to Align Text To the Right in Android TextView?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I need to **right align my text in a TextView** like this. [image: The image text view has the text "SAMPLE TEXT" right indented]

How to achieve this?

Below is my layout.xml file's textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dummyTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dummyTextView"
        android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: android:gravity="right|center"

Comment: Its not working . @ Padma Kumar

Comment: If it is in Relative Layout then set it by dropping at center.

Comment: your Textview height is wrap_content give minHeight="50dp" then check it. it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemDay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:text="Your text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

The problem is:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

You could not align text in **TextView** if you set with is **wrap_content**, please set **fill_parent** or **match_parent** or specified witdh.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` which means its not able to set the gravity because you don't have enough space for the text to align. Try using this instead:

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```